# Implement Javascript image resize

Tags: javascript, file-upload, html5-canvas, filereader

I'm trying to fix Canvas Resize (Downscale) Image, I got jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EWupT/ for image resizing. i have html input field when user upload instantly image show on input field, When adding resize code on my exiting code i got an error. any help greatly appreciated.

My JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var readURL = function(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.width=300;
                canvas.height=234;
                ctx.drawImage(reader, 0, 0, 300, 234);

                $('.profile-pic').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $(".file-upload").on('change', function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    $(".upload-button").on('click', function() {
       $(".file-upload").click();
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="upload-button" id="imageresize"><img class="profile-pic"  src="../images/add-image.png" /></div>
<input id="formFile" id="avatar-2" class="file-upload" type="file" name="my_file"  accept="image/*">
```

I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.
    at FileReader.reader.onload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `filereader.onload` function, inside we can use resize code.
Updated code:

```
$(".upload-button").on('click', function() {
  $(".file-upload").click();
});
var fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = function(event) {
  var image = new Image();

  image.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 380;
    //canvas.height=image.height/1;

    $('#upload-preview').width(500); //pixels

    var hRatio = canvas.width / image.width;
    var vRatio = canvas.height / image.height;
    var ratio = Math.min(hRatio, vRatio);

    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0,
      image.width * ratio, image.height * ratio
    );

    document.getElementById("upload-preview").src = canvas.toDataURL();
  }
  image.src = event.target.result;
};

var uploadImage = function() {
  var uploadImage = document.getElementById("upload-Image");

  if (uploadImage.files.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  var uploadFile = document.getElementById("upload-Image").files[0];
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(uploadFile);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using the `new Image()` function and generating a `HTMLImageElement` object dynamically, add `img.src` after the `onload` function like so:

```js
img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width=300
    canvas.height=234
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 234);
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
};
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/SHo6Fub.jpg';
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SHo6Fub.jpg" width="300" height="234">
```

Comment: that not work, because image link also set dynamically.

Comment: It should work as intended as you can see in the snippet

Comment: can you show that how to implement my own code